# Why is casting in certain generic circumstances necessary?

Tags: c#, generics

In a generic method you need to cast your return variable to an object and then back to the generic type and I understand why that is generally, but what I don't understand is why you need to do that when you've already established what type the variable is in the scope of the return statement. For example, normally I'd do this:

```
public MyType1 obj1;
public MyType2 obj2;

public T GetObject<T>()
{
    if (obj1 is T) return (T)(object)obj1;
    else if (obj2 is T) return (T)(object)obj2;
    else return default(T);
}
```

But my question is, why can't I remove the casting like this:

```
public MyType1 obj1;
public MyType2 obj2;

public T GetObject<T>()
{
    if (obj1 is T) return obj1;
    else if (obj2 is T) return obj2;
    else return default(T);
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler understand that the object is of the correct return type when that's the only type it could be?

Comment: Note: that's not boxing or unboxing unless T actually is a value type (those terms do have specific meaning). For any class, that's just a cast.

Comment: All the code smells.  All of them.  Also, this isn't **boxing**, its *casting*.

Comment: The question "Why doesn't the compiler understand that the object is of the correct return type when that's the only type it could be?" has nothing to do with generics. It won't compile for `string Method(object arg)` .. `if (arg is string) return arg;` either. I believe that the answer is simply because the spec won't allow this kind of inference.

Comment: I think reworded a little, this can be an interesting question.  But I still think it has merit.

Comment: Note that an `is` check requires a box instruction if the object is a value type because the isinst instruction used for the test takes an object reference so your second example actually doesn't avoid all boxing. If the types are reference types, no boxing occurs any way, although an unbox_any instruction is used to do the cast.

Comment: I am suspicious that the way this is being designed isn't optimal. Why are you presenting two different public fields and then letting a method determine which one to return? Please describe a real-world use case for this, because have a hunch there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @Will. That's nice. Why is it smelly? And how would I clean it?

Comment: @ErikE I was attempting to come up with ways to make a generic static helper class to group a variety of different component types in a way that would let me call them solely by an id and type. My question on 'boxing' or apparently casting was because I was under the impression that there was a performance cost, though relatively small I understand, and I was trying to find an optimized way of doing it.

Comment: Please be more concrete. What kind of component types? Why does the caller not know the mapping of, for each desired type, which public field to access to get such a thing?

Comment: The component types represent various UI elements and I don't have direct access to the public field because they are part of a third-party API.

Comment: @cjmarsh you're using a generic argument to determine which value, A or B, to return.  That's so wonky and bad, it's hard to think of why you'd ever want to do this.  I'd love to see the motivation behind this; there's probably a much better and simpler way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The API I'm working with has a container object with a number of possible types of child objects, each with various UI functions. Unlike in say, WPF, I'm unable to reference one of the child elements by a single unique id as the id belongs to the container and the only way to reference the component is by using a function that, from what I've read, performs slowly in a realtime setting. My intention was to catalog a proxy object containing the component elements in a dictionary with the id as the key and get the component by the id and type. I know it's bad but I can't think of an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> The **is** keyword causes a compile-time warning if the expression is known to always be **true** or to always be **false**, but typically evaluates type compatibility at run time.

That is whether `obj1` is of type `T` is not determined by the compiler but is evaluated when the code runs.

Answer (score 3):

You are making incorrect assumptions about generics. To understand this better, imagine this. Let's say you had a base class Base and two sub classes, Sub and VerySub.

If your members were stored as Base then the compiler can only guarantee they are Base. It is the static typing system which generics use. At run time let's say we had a simple function called GetIfVerySub. Let's say it did a test on an object of type Base and discovered it was also a VerySub. That's unknowable at compile time, so to return the downcasted object, you would expect to do a cast or an as.

This is exactly what your generic function is trying to do, but owing to the fact it is generic, it also can work on any type, including ones incompatible with Base.

The better question, though, is why you are doing this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `foo is T; (T)foo` expressions. Use the `as` operator and it solves your problems:

```
public MyType1 obj1;

public T GetObject<T>() where T : class {
    T ret = obj1 as T;
    if( ret != null ) return ret;
    ret = obj2 as T;
    if( ret != null ) return ret;
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unless you constrain `T` to a class.